# Remove protobuf c++ compiled path string from binary

Tags: c++, string, protocol-buffers

When I compile my c++ program that uses Protobuf, and then run the linux `strings` command on the binary, one of the strings is a path to the generated `cc` file, with my home directory and everything. Obviously I'd like to eliminate my home directory and other personal information from the binary.

Where does this path come from and how can I prevent it from making it into the compiled binary?

Comment: Try run strip on binary http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_%28Unix%29. Perhaps it is just debugging info. Just guess..

Comment: @Sergey I have and it hasn't changed anything. The file is a bit smaller though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string comes from the embedded protobuf descriptor, which is used to perform dynamic introspection of protobuf types. Essentially, the descriptor describes your whole `.proto` file. The descriptor itself is encoded in protobuf format; see [google/protobuf/descriptor.proto](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto).

Now, the descriptor normally should *not* contain absolute paths like you describe. It really wants to contain "canonical" paths -- that is, the path name of the proto file relative to the source code root, or in other words, the path that you'd write in an `import` statement for that file. For instance, `descriptor.proto`'s own canonical path is `google/protobuf/descirptor.proto`; to import it, you would write `import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";`.

The reason your descriptors are getting the full absolute filesystem path is because that is the path that you are passing to `protoc`, and you are not passing a `-I` flag to tell `protoc` where the root of your source tree is. Since `protoc` can't figure out the root of the source code, it is falling back to the file system root.

For instance, say your `.proto` file is `/home/foo/myproj/src/frobber/baz.proto`. Say that the `src` directory in this path is your "source root", meaning that you want people to write `import "frobber/baz.proto";` to import your proto file. In that case, you want to invoke `protoc` like this:

```
protoc -I/home/foo/myproj/src /home/foo/myproj/src/frobber/baz.proto
```

Note that if you are running the command from, say, the `myproj` directory, then you probably shouldn't specify an absolute path at all:

```
protoc -Isrc src/frobber/baz.proto
```

It is very important that the `-I` flag here is a textual prefix of the source file name. `protoc` is dumb and only knows how to compare strings. It doesn't, for instance, know what the current directory is:

```
# DOES NOT WORK
cd /home/foo/myproj
protoc -I/home/foo/myproj/src src/frobber/baz.proto
```

And it also cannot canonicalize "..":

```
# DOES NOT WORK: protoc doesn't collapse "xyz/../".
protoc -Isrc xyz/../src/frobber/baz.proto
```

However ".." is OK if it's consistent, because again `protoc` only cares about a prefix match:

```
# OK: Prefix is consistent.
protoc -Ixyz/../src xyz/../src/frobber/baz.proto
```

### If you'd rather not have a descriptor

You can compile your proto files in "lite mode" by placing the following line in your `.proto` file:

```
option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;
```

In this mode, descriptors will not be included at all. Additionally, you can link against the "lite" version of the protobuf runtime library, which is much smaller than the regular version. However, many useful features will be disabled. The whole reflection interface will be gone, and anything that depends on reflection will be gone as well. For example, `TextFormat`, which is what the `DebugString()` method uses to convert messages into text to print for debugging, will be removed, therefore debugging will be harder.

Comment: Thank you for your very very thorough answer!