# Remove protobuf-lite C++ compiled path string from binary dll

Tags: c++, protobuf-c

This question is the same with the problem with [Remove protobuf c++ compiled path string from binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018984/remove-protobuf-c-compiled-path-string-from-binary).

I'm using Protobuf 3.15.8 lite in Visual Studio 2017.
I compiled lite version .lib and compiled my own dll to translate between C++ dll with C# Program.
I do set the release settings in visual studio, such as remove debug info and others, and change protobuf.lib to protobuf-lite.lib and other answers in that question.

The generated dll still contains the paths below (only these four):

```
D:\{mypath}\protobuf-3.15.8\src\google\protobuf\message_lite.cc
D:\{mypath}\protobuf-3.15.8\src\google\protobuf\wire_format_lite.cc
D:\{mypath}\protobuf-3.15.8\src\google\protobuf\arena.cc
D:\{mypath}\protobuf-3.15.8\src\google\protobuf\parse_context.h
```

What more configurations I can do to solve this problem? and what causes this problem?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=msvc-160

Have you tried the /PDBALTPATH and /PDBSTRIPPED options?

Comment: I tried, not working.